# Как обойти constant expression required?

Tags: java

Есть некий статистический метод который должен выполнять определенную деятельность.
Упростив до максимума выглядит он подобным образом

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int forTest = 1;
        test(forTest);

    }

    public static void test(int testValue) {
        int m;
        int n = 1;

        switch (testValue) {
            case n: {
                //todo
            }
        }
    }
}
```

На строке выбора `case n: {` возникает ошибка `constant expression required`.
Из-за чего возникает данная проблема? 
Каким образом проектировать методы и классы для исключения возможности данной ошибки в будущем?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

У вас проблема не с проектированием, а с синтаксисом языка. После `case` может идти только константа, но не переменная:

```
switch (testValue) {
  case 1: {
    // todo
  }
}
```

Если к такому виду привести код нельзя - не заморачивайтесь и воспользуйтесь оператором `if`:

```
if (testValue == 1) {
  // todo
}
```

Comment: Благодарю! Проблема в том что все значения используемые для case генерируются во время исполнения программы и использование оператора switch обусловлено большим, на мой взгляд, количеством выбора. Согласитесь 12 подряд идущих if else if выглядят не очень корректно. Правильно ли я понимаю, что единственный способ это вышеописанный?

Comment: @mamba0767 зависит от того какие у вас условия, иногда можно применить шаблон проектирования Стратегия, посмотрите тут: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10175950/1646082

Comment: @mamba0767 если значения генерируются во время исполнения программы, то switch вы не сможете использовать. А конкретно в приведённом примере можете написать final int n = 1, тогда n будет считаться константой и её можно использовать в case

Answer (score 1):

Используй "final" при декларировании:

```
public static void test(int testValue) {
        int m;
        final int n = 1;

        switch (testValue) {
            case n: {
                //todo
            }
        }
    }
```

@Pavel Mayorov: и почему он должен использовать "if", если "switch" быстрее?

Answer (score -4):

Используй Kotlin язык. Мне помогло

```
for (File curFile : listOfFiles) {
        if (curFile.isDirectory()) {
            switch (curFile.getName()) {
                case String.valueOf(xls_xlsx): //сдесь проблема - xls_xlsx это тип Enum (константа)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Теперь я в `IDEA` создал файл `Kotlin`'a.
Скопировал туда код `Java` (весь файл или только функцию). Соглашаюсь что трансформируй мне в `Kotlin` (ждем некоторое время)
И готово - код `Kotlin`'a теперь мой такой (и без проблем константа моя есть в `switch` (т.е. в `when`)

```
for (curFile in listOfFiles!!) {
        if (curFile.isDirectory) {
            when (curFile.name) {
                xls_xlsx.toString() -> { //проблема решена. Компилируется.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Если не знали `Kotlin`, то возможно у вас появился вопрос "как вызывать теперь Котлин из Джавы? Это все сделали за вас. Берем гуглим и есть простые ответы.

Почему я пишу этот пост. Потому что я пишу под себя и для себя. Мне нужно удобство и простота кода. Я решил через `Kotlin`

Comment: Нужно плагин использовать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330311/how-do-you-compile-javakotlin-project-using-maven